# Is Serverless Cloud Native too?

Tags: serverless

Is Server-less a subset or attribute of Cloud Native? Or is it another way round -- Is Cloud Native a subset or attribute of Server-less?

Nathan Aw (Singapore)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Cloud native** is a more general approach to building and running applications that take advantage of cloud computing. **Serverless** is more of an execution model in the cloud.

A **Cloud native** stack will usually aim to make use of containers and microservices:
 
Each part of the stack is packaged in its own container. This promotes reproducibility, transparency, and resource isolation. Dynamically orchestrated containers are then actively scheduled and managed to optimize resource utilization. 
 
Applications are also segmented or broken-down into microservices, which are more easily testable and maintainable, are loosely-coupled, and independently deployable.

**Serverless** describes a model of providing backend services on an as-used basis.The cloud provider (*AWS Lambda/Google Cloud Functions/Azure Functions*) is responsible for executing a piece of code by dynamically allocating the resources.

Many of today's apps apply elements of both.